# How to determine the end of a loop when the array size is unknown?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm creating an Alamofire request to download images from a server based on a number of array values from a JSON file that are not always the same.
For example:

```
for i in 0..<var1.count {
  Alamofire.request(.....
    for j in 0..<var2.count {
      Alamofire.request(.....
        ...
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that var1 and var2 have no fixed depth size. The size is being random and sometimes is zero.
I need to call separate Alamofire request inside those loops. 
Everything works fine and I get all the images downloaded correctly when the loop is done.

The only problem is when I initiate an animated loader until all images are being downloaded, I can't seem to figure out when to dismiss it.
I know that Alamofire has a progress indicator but that would help only if I call it once. But in my case I have to call it many times.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `var2` in your sample if known before `Alamofire.request()`, or it is known after ?

Comment: It's known only after the result from the first Alamofire request.

Comment: Do you known how many varN do you have (even if "empty")?

Comment: It actually varies depends on how many available images are in the server. The images are divided into categories and subcategories. Each subcategory might have from 0 to unlimited images and each image can be with one size up to 3 different sizes.

Comment: The code is just simplifying the idea. If this can be figured out, then it can be applied to the actual code which is more than 650 lines